# how to render views under mail in controller?

Tags: yii, yii2

i want to send latest tender list to my subscribers. the view is located under common/mail/layout  the view name is `tenderlist.php`
i have controller in frontend, called SiteController  and i  have views under Site folder that is `tenderlist.php`. here the code works fine and giving the list of tenders, now i want to send tenders to multiple users using `swiftmailer` as a result, i copy the page `tenderlist.php` to mail/layout folder.
the email configuration is correct but i cannot send the tenderlist to users

this works fine and sends  to emails if `tenderlist.php` is pure html code that is static data.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => 'layouts/tenderlist'])
```

but if tenderlist querys come from database it gives me error:
here is the view code of `tenderlist.php`

//view page of tenderlist.php under mail/layouts

```
<?php foreach ($etender as $post): ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">

      <a href="detail?id=<?=html::encode($post['id'])?> "> <?=html::encode($post['bidtitle'])?> </a>  </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

//in my sitecontroller actionTenderlist()

```
return $this->render('@common/mail/layout/tenderlist', [
                                    'etender'=>$tenders,       ]);
```

//when i run this it gives error

```
Undefined variable: etender
```

Comment: the view part is:

Comment: //view page of tenderlist.php under mail/layouts
<?php foreach ($etender as $post): ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  
      <a href="detail?id=<?=html::encode($post['id'])?> "> <?=html::encode($post['bidtitle'])?> </a>  </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>  

//in my sitecontroller actionTenderlist()

 return $this->render('@common/mail/layout/tenderlist', [
                   'etender'=>$tenders,    ]); 
              
//when i run this it gives error
Undefined variable: etender

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you need to do:
Advanced Yii2 app, `common/config/main-local.php`:

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'mailer' => [
       'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    ],
    //...
]
```

Your send mail function:

```
Yii::$app
        ->mailer
        ->compose(
            [
                'html' => 'template-html', //or any sub folder of yor template like "templates/orders/template-html" located in common/mail
                'text' => 'template-text',
            ],
            [
                //any vars like
                'user' => $this->user,
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['appEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
        ->setTo($this->user->email)
        ->setSubject($title)
        ->send()
```

Hope it helps.

> Also Make sure you access data (Or you check that data exist) before you pass it in to the mail template. And also check your `frontend/runtime/log/app.log` if any errors occur.

Thanks to Muhammad Omer Aslam